# What does the "imports on/off" switch do in golang tour?

Tags: go

I'm following the tutorial in https://tour.golang.org/

There are some options on the top right corner of the interactive window.

[image: Golang tour interactive window options]

**Syntax On** is obvious which enables/disables syntax highlighting of the code inside the window.

The other one, **Imports On**, which I tried to switch on/off and run the code but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What does this option do exactly?

Comment: If you use a package from the standard lib, when you click "Format" with Imports On, it will add the import lines.  I believe it may run `goimports` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Imports On/Off** enables or disables [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports).

To test out an example, remove (or add, or modify) any of the import lines in one of the examples, then click **Format**. This will automatically add/remove imports based on the packages used in the code.

`goimports` is very convenient to have as a save hook in your editor to automatically set imports for you (and cleanup, which is something that can easily be forgotten).

Answer (score 0):

automatically imports the package you have mentioned when you hit format